# ScrollView не работает в Android Studio. Приложение вылетает

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Всем привет. Неделю назад делал собственное приложение на Андроид - конвертер единиц. Главная страница состоит из слоя "Названия приложения" RelativeLayout, затем идет другой RelativeLayout с заголовком "Выберите физическую величину" и радиогруппой со списком величин от длины до массы, а в самом конце идет обычная кнопка "Выбрать". В конце разработки обнаружил, что при повороте в горизонтальное положение нижние радиокнопки скрываются, и неплохо бы было туда добавить пролистывание, то бишь ScrollView. Посмотрел урок, как это делается, сделал все по образу и подобию, и обнаружил, что мое приложение вылетело. Пытался перед созданием этого вопроса поискать ответы в аналогичном, но у того участника все организовано по другому - сначала ScrollView, потом слои LinearLayout. У меня скорее наоборот, только вместо LinearLayout RelativeLayout и RadioGroup. Поэтому и создал этот вопрос, вдруг причина в другом. Ошибок в оформлении Android Studio не выдает. В чем может быть причина?

Вот код с xml файла:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="ExtraText">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_layer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@color/violet_1"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/app_name_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:text="Конвертер единиц"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="27sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/second_layer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/top_layer"
        android:background="@color/cyan_green"
        >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="-12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="90dp"
            android:onClick="showDeveloperInfo"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:minWidth="48dp"
            android:minHeight="48dp"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_info_details" />

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:ignore="ScrollViewCount">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/unit_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:onClick="showDeveloperInfo"
                android:text="Выберите физическую
           величину:"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="25sp" />

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radio_group_units"
                android:layout_below="@+id/unit_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/length"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Длина"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
                    android:checked="true"/>
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/area"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Площадь"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="25dp"/>
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/volume"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Объем"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="25dp"/>
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/speed"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Скорость"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="25dp"/>
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/temperature"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Температура"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="25dp"/>
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/mass"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Масса"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="25dp"/>
            </RadioGroup>

        </ScrollView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/choose_unit"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
            android:onClick="button_clc"
            android:text="Выбрать"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Всё просто - у ScrollView должен быть только один ребёнок. Т.е. вам надо обернуть всё содержимое ScrollView в какой-то контейнер. Например во FrameLayout.

Ну и надо смотреть в логи - по идее там это же и написано.